# #Laravel How do I store value with switch-button

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store value from switch button but I can't save value when switch off
in my blade.

```html
<input name="serial_status[]" type="checkbox"
data-toggle="switchbutton" checked data-onstyle="success"
data-size="xs" data-onlabel="ใช้งาน" data-offlabel="ไม่ใช้งาน">
```

In my controller:

```php
if ($product->save()) {
    $product->productSerials()->delete();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->serial_name); $i++) {
        if ($request->get('serial_status')) {
            $status = 'active';
        } else {
            $status = 'inactive';
        }
        $items[] = [
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'serial_name' => $request->serial_name[$i],
            'serial_status' => $status,
        ];

    }

    ProductSerial::insert($items);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check if your checkbox is active or not with the help of ajax. then pass data to your controller, something like this:

```
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
  
    // check your checkbox if active or not
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){

        var checked = true;

    }else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){

        var checked = false;

    }

    // csrf token
    var headers = { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') };

    // passing data to laravel controller
    var data = {
            
        'id': "1",
        "serial_num":$("#checkbox").attr("name"),
        "status": checked

        };

    // ajax post request
    $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'/YourControllerUrl',
               headers: headers,
               data:data,
               success:function(data) {

                  console.log(data.msg);

                }


        });

});
```